# Wix toolset: continue installation after reboot system

Tags: wix, wix3

I need to develop an installer that would copy files to the system that are already used by the system and can only be replaced after a reboot. Therefore, I first save the files to a temporary folder. I am performing a registry cheat and asking you to reboot the system. And when a reboot occurs, files must be moved from the temporary folder. How to continue installation after system reboot?

I couldn't find a way to implement it the Wix documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Stop. You're trying too hard. Just install the files normally. If they are in use, the Windows Installer will do all the work to schedule their replacement during the restart. Trying to do it yourself is more fragile and way more complex.